# Creating randomly skewed random data

Tags: random

I am trying to create dummy survey data. I need to simulate about 100,000 respondents. There are about 20 questions where the respondents can rate various statements with 0 - 5. Also, there are different respondent splits, e.g. male/female, age etc.

My problem is that using random data generation (using Excel RANDBETWEEN or even online number generators), all the data tends towards the mean. So all questions and all splits work out around 3.

I need a way to create random data, where the average of each set differs from the other sets. So each question should be likely to have a different average, males should have a different average than females etc.

Thanks

Comment: Just randomize some means and variances in step 1 (e.g. one mean/variance for each question; one for male/female which could mean something like an offset); then sample where each object uses it's previously sampled mean/variance.

Comment: Could you give an example, in VBA for instance?

Comment: No sry, i don't use excel and vba. But it's easy to add a column of size (n_questions) and fill this column with random values in range(0,5) = mean per question. Do this with a second column = variance. Then you can reference your random-sampling with these two columns as parameters for your distribution. The programming is very straighforward. The stochastic modelling is tougher because it depends on what you want to achieve. In general i would expect the answers to these questions as a normal-distributed random variable (instead of uniform; maybe given some per-question params).